# Sending email using asp.net error

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have the following page with an email form:

http://www.tronitech.com/lp/impact-md.aspx

When you click submit, you get a 404 error page (because it jumped back a directory - loosing the /lp/)

The code for sending the email is in the associated .aspx.cs file in the lp directory.

Any ideas why it is loosing the sub-directory and trying to access the page in the root?

I have the same form/structure on a page in the root and everything works fine.

http://www.tronitech.com/Support.aspx

Thanks

Brett

Here is my form code - I'm not setting anything:

```
<form id="MailForm" method="post" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing this part of your HTML page:

```
<form name="MailForm" method="post" action="impact-md.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="MailForm">
```

To something like this:

```
<form name="MailForm" method="post" action="/lp/impact-md.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return  WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="MailForm">
```

Maybe the form needs to have that `/lp/` in the `action=""` address there.

Comment: This is the code for the form code above...I'm not setting this.

Comment: Did you see the `action="/lp/impact-md.aspx"` part?  That is what you probably need to change... unless you decide to try the `<base>` method.  Having that additional directory path in the action helps the script know what script you are trying to call on `<form>` POST.

Comment: Like @Kevin referred to in the post below... if you have to keep the `<base>` in there... make sure to tell your <form>'s action about where your impact-md.aspx script is in relation to the `<base>` URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave action ="" blank

Comment: I'm not setting this - see edited question above, I posted the form code.

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem:

Remove this from the document HEAD:

```
<base href="http://www.tronitech.com/" />
```

By declaring a base href you are telling the browser that all **relative links** contained within the document start from that specified base location.

[W3C BASE ELEMENT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4)

The form action in your page (`action="impact-md.aspx"`) is a **relative link** as it does not begin with a solidus (slash). Hence, the current path is ignored and the form POST is directed by the web browser to `http://www.tronitech.com/impact-md.aspx` precisely as you told it to do!

Comment: I'm using the base URL to keep all my links working for includes, navigation and such throughout the site.  I can't change this.

Comment: If you need to keep <base href="http://www.tronitech.com/" /> in, then you can set the postback url of the button to impact-md.aspx and it should work.

Comment: @Brett A `<base>` element affects ALL relative links. If you keep the `<base>` element then you MUST make the form `action` attribute NON-RELATIVE: `/lp/impact-md.aspx`. Actually, since it's an ASP.NET control you'll probably go with `~/lp/impact-md.aspx`. One or the other.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for this.  I will test this out today and see what happens.